# jOOQ converter from String to List<MyType> in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, jooq

I'm working on a rare case where I find storing JSON in a RDBMS field acceptable. JSON document is an array or key-value objects.

So, the [jOOQ converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/) converts from `String` to `List<MyType>`. I'm doing this in Kotlin and that's where the fun starts - with generics.

**Converter**

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class MyTypeListConverter :
    AbstractConverter<String, List<MyType>>(String::class.java, List::class.java as Class<List<MyType>>) {...}
```

**Generator configuration**

```
database {
    inputSchema = "PUBLIC"
    includes = ".*"
    recordVersionFields = "(version|VERSION)"
    customTypes {
        customType {
            name = "MyTypeListConverter"
            type = "java.util.List<mypackage.MyType>"
            converter = "mypackage.MyTypeListConverter"
        }
    }
    forcedTypes {
        forcedType {
            name = "MyTypeListConverter"
            expression = ".*Event\\.MYFIELD"
            types = ".*"
            converter = "mypackage.MyTypeListConverter"
        }
    }
}
```

**Generated jOOQ code**

```
public final TableField<EventRecord, List<MyType>> MYFIELD = 
createField("TITLE", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.CLOB.nullable(false), this, "", new MyTypeListConverter());
```

**Problem**

The generated jOOQ code does not compile due to incompatible types. `List<MyType>` as declared by `MYFIELD` is not compatible to `List<? extends MyType>` which is inferred from the `createField()` method.

Ultimately this may be more about Java-Kotlin generics interoperability than about jOOQ. The `? extends MyType` invariant in the error message is suspicious.