# How can i configure jOOQ code generator to generate Set<T> instead of Array<T>?

Tags: kotlin, generics, jooq, jooq-codegen

I am working with a database where values are stored in an `ARRAY` column which has the semantics of a Java `Set`, most importantly that ordering does not matter.

Currently, the jOOQ generator generates POJOs and Records with `Array<T>` type for those columns. This is problematic, because two arrays don't equal if their ordering is different.

I tried creating a custom converter, however, obviously defining the `toType` as `Set<String>::class.java` won't compile because of type erasure(?)

```
class ArrayToSetConverter() :
    AbstractConverter<Array<String>, Set<String>>(Array<String>::class.java, Set<String>::class.java) { ... }
```

Compilation error:

```
Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal
```

Is there another way of achieving my goal?

Similar (unfortunately unanswered) question: [jOOQ converter from String to List<MyType> in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946951/jooq-converter-from-string-to-listmytype-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With type erasure, I don't think you can formally create a `Class<Set<String>>` type reference in neither Java nor kotlin. But you don't have to. Just do this:

```kotlin
class ArrayToSetConverter() : AbstractConverter<Array<String>, Set<String>>(
  Array<String>::class.java, 
  Set::class.java as Class<Set<String>> // Unsafe cast here
) { ... }
```